# Dragging multiple polygons on Canvas rerender in React Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, react, mapcanvas

I am using [React Leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) to render Leaflet map and [Leaflet.Path.Drag](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag) to drag multiple polygons together. Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-jennings-t25ex).

I have a lot of polygons and would like to drag multiple polygons with [preferCanvas](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-prefercanvas) option. If I try to drag multiple polygons with `preferCanvas`, it doesn't work. Dragging makes duplicate polygons and polygons are not visible during dragging.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bash-mo7ke)

Cross-post from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443135/dragging-multiple-polygons-on-canvas-rerender-in-react-leaflet).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering overlapping polygons without holes in multipolygon in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388986/rendering-overlapping-polygons-without-holes-in-multipolygon-in-leaflet)

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: It doesn't answer this question, only the previous question.