# Rendering overlapping polygons without holes in multipolygon in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, multi-polygon

Is there a way to render overlapping polygons without holes in multipolygon in Leaflet?

I found Leaflet has an open [issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6173).

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-browser-t9glj)

I am asking because I have a bound polygon that contains inner polygons.

[image]

I would need to drag them all together, but it doesn't work in canvas mode. It could work if I can render this as a multipolygon. This is a follow-up question on my previous [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388984/dragging-multiple-polygons-on-canvas-rerender-in-react-leaflet) and cross-post from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470475/rendering-overlapping-polygons-without-holes-in-multipolygon-in-leaflet).

Comment: A valid simple feature MultiPolygon cannot have overlapping parts. That does not prevent Leaflet from dealing with them. I do not know if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just copy-paste [my response to Leaflet bug #6173](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6173#issuecomment-790615562) :

---

I'm reading the OGC's Simple Feature Access specification (again), to remind myself about the formal definitions of Polygons and MultiPolygons. Let me quote page 31:

```
6.1.14 MultiPolygon
A MultiPolygon is a MultiSurface whose elements are Polygons.
The assertions for MultiPolygons are as follows.
a) The interiors of 2 Polygons that are elements of a MultiPolygon may not intersect.
```

Heck, it even comes with pretty pictures:
[image]
So, MultiPolygons which have overlapping members are not valid MultiPolygons. As such, I think Leaflet has no obligation to handle that invalid case.

See also [#3763 (comment)](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3763#issuecomment-133398821) (re: `fillRule` option for SVG renderer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that multipolygon with overlapping polygons is not a valid polygon. However, I am wondering if there is a way to deal with that. I tried `fillRule: 'nonzero'` but it doesn't make any difference [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cori-871zx)

Comment: Well, duh, the way to deal to invalid overlapping (multi)polygons is to turn them into valid geometries. Whether that needs a [union](https://turfjs.org/docs/#union) approach or a [difference](https://turfjs.org/docs/#difference) approach depends on your use case and it's up to you (and not up to Leaflet). Otherwise, this is a case of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in%2C_garbage_out).